# IIS7 URL Rewrite - Why isn't this working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have this simple rewrite, yet for some reason I cannot work out why it's not working:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="men-s-watches" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)/men-s-watches(.*)" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/mens-watches" appendQueryString="false" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Hopefully someone can point out my noob mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally in IIS7 url rewrite module is used and you can assign rules like this.

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rewriteMaps>
      <rewriteMap name="usr_rule">
    </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>
  <rules>
    <rule name="men-s-watches">
      <match url="^([0-9]+)/men-s-watches/([0-9]+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="men-s-watches/default.aspx?id={R:1}&amp;p={R:2}" />
    </rule>
    </rules>
   </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure my match url is correct, the Test pattern tool says it's perfect.  I'm not interested in any querystring information, this is just a catch-all for the category to avoid 404s after a site rebuild - porting from magento to asp.net mvc.

Comment: ok i tested your rule, its correct, kindly provide sample url and rewrite url to check your pattern against it.

Comment: www.anydomain.com/men-s-watches should redirect to www.anydomain.com/men-watches

Comment: if there is no dynamic querystring value passed, then your task simply worked with me via the following rules

Comment: <match url="men-s-watches" /><action type="Redirect" url="mens-watches" appendQueryString="false" />

Comment: (.*) replaced with dynamic value {R:1} if needed in url then adjust.

Comment: QueryString may be passed in, but the rule should drop it.

Comment: Your much simpler rule (without the regex) worked.  Not sure why the regex isn't working.